# Gtk 3.4 puts default padding around widgets in event boxes?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

I'm using python gtk 3.4 and seem to get 1 or 2 pixel wide padding round elements packed into event boxes. I tried getting rid of it by setting the padding to zero in the CSS and python, but no luck.  However when I run my code on my laptop which has gtk 3.8, there's no padding. Has anyone had this problem and figured out how to get rid of it? I wondered if it might be a bug in gtk 3.4

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've solved my problem.  I hope this helps someone else:
If you set the properties of a widget in the CSS of Gtk 3.4, it seems to be frequently ignored when it becomes the child widget.  So, to remove all padding (in my case):

```
GtkContainer GtkBox,
GtkContainer GtkEvent,
GtkContainer GtkFixed,
GtkBox GtkEventBox,
GtkBox GtkFixed,
GtkBox GtkGrid,
GtkBox GtkContainer,
GtkGrid GtkEventBox,
GtkFixed GtkImage,
GtkFixed GtkEventBox,
GtkWindow GtkGrid,
GtkWindow GtkBox {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped me, somwhat indirectly; I set both inner-border of the outer gtk-window and all inside gtk-boxes to 0. I needed that to have a completely black widget without any non-black border/frame area, as I was trying to re-create a game written in SDL in ruby-gtk3.